# need advice for type of TCP server to cater for this type of application

Tags: c#, c++, tcp

The requirement of the TCP server:

1. receive from each client and send
   result back to same client (the
   server only do this)
2. require to cater for 100 clients
3. speed is an important factor, ie:
   even at 100 client connections, it should not be laggy.

For now I have been using C# async method, but I find that I always encounter laggy at around 20 connections. By laggy I mean taking around almost 15-20 seconds to get the result. At around 5-10 connections, time to get result is almost immediate.
Actually when the tcp server got the message, it will interact with a dll which does some processing to return a result. Not exactly sure what is the workflow behind it but at small scale you do not see any problem, so I thought the problem might be with my TCP server.

Right now, I thinking of using a sync method. Doing so, I will have a while loop to block the accept method, and spawn a new thread for each client after accept. But at 100 connections, it is definitely overkill.

Chance upon IOCP, not exactly sure, but it seems to be like a connection pool, as the way it handles tcp is quite like the normal way.

For these TCP methods I am also not sure whether it is a better option to open and close connection each time message needs to be passed. On average, message are passed from each client at around 5-10 min interval.

Another alternative might be to use a web, (looking at generic handler) to form only 1 connection with the server. Any message that needs to be handled will be passed to this generic handler, which then sends and receive message from the server.

Need advice from especially those who did TCP in large scale. I do not have 100 PC for me to test out, so quite hard for me. Language wise C# or C++ will do, I'm more familar with C#, but will consider porting to C++ for the speed.

Comment: What does the server need to *do* between getting a client's request and sending the response back to the client?  15-20 seconds with 20 connections seems weirdly high unless you're overloading _other_ resources, e.g., connections to a database -- hard to guess unless you tell us about that "middle part";-).  (Please edit your Q to fully clarify that part). I've done a lot of large-scale TCP systems, in many languages, and even in Python (not known for blazing speed;-) I'd *not* expect a "knee up" in response time (due to anything _intrinsic_) between 5 and 20 connections!-)

Comment: @Alex, yes in between it is doing other thing. But I do not have any idea what is the work flow behind it. Ok, will listen to u by adding those additional steps.

Comment: @C_Rance: While there is some good general advice being given to you, I think Alex had the right idea. You should not be looking at the protocol level so long as it's likely that the time is being spent on the actual work. Try this: dummy up the server so that it immediately returns some plausible cached data and see how it scales. If it handles 100 clients without delays, you'll know where to focus your optimization efforts.

Comment: @Steven I cant really find out the fault lies with which. I just edited the question and mention that it had a dll attached for processing. Morever, I do not have 100 PC to test the actual setup.

Comment: You don't need 100 PC's, just 100 simultaneous TCP/IP connections. Unless you can account for where all the time went, you're not going to be able to speed things up effectively.

Comment: You don't need 100 PCs to test, just 100 client processes. We've used custom C# clients (firing batches of 10 requests), and multiple browsers (for testing an AMQP app) to simulate a far larger number of actual users. Obviously it's not real world testing, but good for shaking down problems before you get that far.
If you are Internet facing, another way to do testing is to rent a load of temporary virtual machines (the Amazon elastic compute model) to fire requests back at you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be doing it wrong. I personally wrote C# based servers that could handle 1000+ connections, sending more than 1 message per second, with <10ms response time, on commodity hardware.

If you have such high response times it must be your server process that is causing blocking. Perhaps contention on locks, perhaps plain bad code, perhaps blocking on external access leading to thread pool exhaustion. Unfortunately, there are plenty of ways to screw this up, and only few ways to get it right. There are good guidelines out there, starting with the fundamentals covered in Rick Vicik's [High Performance Windows Programming](http://rusanu.com/2008/11/11/high-performance-windows-programs/) articles, going over the [SocketAsyncEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx) example which covers the most performant way of writing socket apps in .Net since the advent of [Socket Performance Enhancements in Version 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968780.aspx) and so on and so forth.

If you find yourself lost at the task ahead (as it seems you happen to be) I would urge you to embrace an established communication framework, perhaps [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) with a net binding, and use the [declarative service model programming of WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731067.aspx). This way you'll piggyback on the WCF performance. While this may not be enough for some, it will get you far enough, much further than you are right now for sure, with regard to performance.

Comment: @Remus: I hope you won't mind a slightly off-topic question... Have you ever run into bugs in the new `Socket` async APIs?

Comment: For what it's worth, properly configured WCF has proven to be quite fast.

Comment: Ok thanks, by far u give me the most guide.
1st time dealing with 100 connections, and using the dll, not sure which is causing me the problems. But if you say yours can handle 1k plus connections, i guess it ties down to the dll.

Comment: Any since I am using async, is there any other way to hopefully improve it, given the number of connections that I have to handle? I have used SocketAsyncEventArgs in silverlight and grown to like it.

Comment: dun mind , but I also have another application which I am testing on socket async is actually using from the same sample u gave. just that when doing process send. I not very sure is what I'm doing correct. at this part:"
Interlocked.Add(ref m_totalBytesRead, e.BytesTransferred);
e.SetBuffer(e.Offset, e.BytesTransferred);
//this just echo back
"
I interlock it then set the buffer to the string that i wants.
e.SetBuffer(new_buffer,0, new_bufferlength);

Comment: @C_Rance: You can give a try to Sampled Profiling that comes with VS (aka. 'F1 Profiler'). See Find Application Bottlenecks with Visual Studio Profiler http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx.

Comment: @Stephen Clearly: no, not really. Why, did you encounter any problem?

Comment: @C_Rance: can you post, perhaps a new question, the relevant parts of the code?

Comment: @C_Rance: and btw, at around 300-400 connections with repeated test runs you'll start hitting long delays due to TCP/IP port exhaustion. You need to edit the registry on the server, see http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/10/29/port-exhaustion-and-you-or-why-the-netstat-tool-is-your-friend.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560610%28BTS.20%29.aspx and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196271

Comment: @Remus: No; I haven't used them at all yet. I've heard *rumors* of bugs under high-load conditions (all in the Desktop CLR, not SL), but haven't found any reproducible test cases.

Comment: thanks very much guys, will do some profiling with Remus's link.
Very kind of u guys to keep coming and guide me

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why C# should be any worse than C++ in this situation - chances are that you've not yet hit upon the 'right way' to handle the incoming connections.  Spawning off a separate thread for each client would certainly be a step in the right direction, assuming that workload for each thread is more I/O bound than CPU intensive.  Whether you spawn off a thread per connection or use a thread pool to manage a number of threads is another matter - and something to determine through experimentation and also whilst considering whether 100 clients is your maximum!

Comment: OK, this I roughly guessed will be problem for spawning thread. Cause I believe that number of threads a PC is able to handle is proportionally to the number of CPU. But C# and C++, not sure the comparison, read online regarding IOCP,some say C# better, others commend on C++

Comment: Uhm, you should be using a thread pool, not spawning threads.

Comment: ne thread per client is stupid. Sorry - that blunt. IIS should be taken as example: que3ue requests, use a thread pool to handle requests.

Comment: ok, thanks Steven. So can this link be considered as threadpool?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx